# Dividing react-native Animated.Values

Tags: react-native

I want to produce an Animated.Value that is the result of dividing a constant by another Animated.Value.

```
const originalSize = 255;
const currentSize = this.props.someAnimatedValue;

// This method doesn't exist, but it's what I want:
const animatedScaleFactor = Animated.divide(originalSize, currentSize);
```

```

Since there is no `Animated.divide()` method, I only have at my disposal `someAnimatedValue.interpolate()`, which I can use to map an input range to an output range with a custom easing curve, `Animated.multiply()`, and `Animated.modulus()`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### UPDATE - use [Animated.Divide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#divide) instead.

Old answer:

Figured out how to get what I want f(x) = 1/x using an interpolator and custom easing function:

```
import React, {
    Animated,
    Component,
    View
} from 'react-native';

export default class EasingTest extends Component {

    state = {
        input: new Animated.Value(0)
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const max = 937;
        const output = this.state.input.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0,max],
            outputRange: [0,1/max],
            easing: t => 1 / t
        });

        setInterval(() => {
            const input = this.state.input.__getValue();
            const expected = 1 / input;
            const actual = output.__getValue();
            const error = Math.abs(expected - actual) / max;
            console.info(`f(${input}) = ${actual}   (expected ${expected}, error ${Math.round(error * 100)}%`);
        }, 200);

        Animated.timing(this.state.input, {
            toValue: max,
            duration: 1000
        }).start();
    }


    render() {
        return <View />
    }
}
```

Comment: This may well have worked for you but is not the correct answer... you should not be accessing a Animated.Value's value direct 1. it transmits value changes over the bridge (performance issues) and 2. this access is likely to be dropped in coming releases (see doc).

Comment: @JonathanMiles right you are. Also, it looks like Animated.Divide() was added recently, and that should handle this use-case nicely.